# MongoDb subdocument array elements quantity increase update not working

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb subdocument is like :

```
{
 _id:"57beb7396366ebda090bf5ca"
category:"Test"
code:"L-001"
created:"2016-08-25T09:15:37.184Z"
description:"test"
name:"Litu"
price:2
variant:[{
_id:"57beb7396366ebda090bf5ce"
color:"Red"
quantity:2
size:"XL"
},{
_id:"57beb7396366ebda090bf5fe"
color:"Black"
quantity:6
size:"XXL"
}]
```

}

I want to decrease the quantity which color : black & size : XXL

I have tried :

```
Product.update({
        '_id' : req.body.id, 
        'variant.color' : req.body.color, 
        'variant.size' : req.body.size
        },
        {
            $inc: { 'variant.quantity' : -(req.body.quantity)}
        })
```

But got error. Error :

MongoError: cannot use the part (variant of variant.quantity) to traverse the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the fields within an array, use numbered positions/positional operator(`$`) for updates.

In this case, use the positional operator `$`. It will update the first element in the array that matches the query.

```
$inc: { 'variant.$.quantity' : -(req.body.quantity)}
```

Comment: @Md.NazmulHossainBilash On Stack Overflow we say thank you by [accepting answers which helped us](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). There's a green checkmark next to the answer on the left which you tick :)